# Sortable code when executed is not performing the desired action

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
driver.get("https://letcode.in/sortable");
        
        WebElement From = driver.findElement(By.id("sample-box1"));
        WebElement To = driver.findElement(By.id("sample-box1"));
        
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        
        actions.clickAndHold(From).moveToElement(To).release(To).build().perform();
```

When the above code is executed the list in To do is not moved to Done.

Answer (score 0):

```
    driver.get("https://letcode.in/sortable");
    WebElement from = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()=' Get to work']"));
    WebElement to=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()=' Get up']"));
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    Actions a=new Actions(driver);
    a.clickAndHold(from).moveToElement(to).release(to).perform();
```

in order to move

1. Pick up groceries--->use //div[text()=' Pick up groceries']
2. Go home------------->use //div[text()=' Go home']
3. Fall asleep--------->use //div[text()=' Fall asleep']